# Convert a hashcode to its binary representation

Tags: python, hash, hashcode, adler32

I compute the hash code for the word "tropical" using the Adler32 algorithm.
The result is the number "260768607"
How can I convert the above number to its binary representation?
Thank you

Comment: What language are you using?  We need more information.

Comment: I would like to do it in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the `bin()` builtin function.

So for your number this would look like this:

```
bin(260768607) # Result: '0b1111100010110000001101011111'
```

Hope this helped, good luck!

Edit: If you need too remove the `0b` part, you can use this code:

```
int(str(temp)[2:])
```

Comment: Great man thanks! One last question: I get this result "0b111....". What is that "b"?

Comment: 0b is a prefix meaning 'binary'. Similar to 0x, which means 'hexadecimal'. You can remove using your preferred string replace / substring / whatever function.

Comment: Similar too the 0x that goes in front of a hexadecimal value in python, a binary value will be preceded by a 0b.  If you want I can update my original answer with a way to get a string/int without the 0b if that would be easier for you.

Comment: If you could it would be great!(update your answer with a way to remove it :) )

Comment: I will accept it. It was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @PanosTheo I updated my post to show how to remove the 0b part.  You can remove the int() cast if you want it as a string :)

Comment: @phantom Once again. Thank you sir!